# OpenCV and Mat vectors: assignment with copyTo and clone()

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have tried to look for solution myself, but I have spent so much time and still no use.

Here is the issue: I am capturing frames (from std camera) and putting them into buffer - vector (of Mat). When I take a frame, I put it into first position and all of the rest are pushed to the right, like this:

Let say we have a vector of Mats {1 2 3}, then I capture frame 0 and I must have {0 1 2}.

I have defined vector for this purpose, but when pushing elements, I face weird behaviour. Here is my code (objectPatches is Mat vector, frameHSV is simple Mat):

```
        for (vector<Mat>::size_type j = objectPatches.size() - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
        objectPatches[j - 1].copyTo(objectPatches[j]); // DOES NOT

        objectPatches[j] = objectPatches[j - 1].clone(); //WORKS
    }
    frameHSV.copyTo(objectPatches[0]);
```

When I try to update buffer using copyTo(), all buffer values are filled with the same value (are the same images) and I do not get so called "wave" of pictures (changing wave), however, when I try to do the same with clone(), it does work fine and I get the result. What is the reason for this assignment? Is there something I miss?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT 1:

Before the loop, objectPatches already hold images of the same size, so I mean that vector is fully initialized and does have some init data assigned. In loop step it only has to rearrange those images to the right.

EDIT 2:

vector objectPatches, when initialized, is filled with push_back() function. Code clipping:

```
Mat capframe;
capFromCamera.read(capFrame);
objectPatches.push_back(capFrame);
```

So that means, based on Micka answer, that they share the same data array.

Comment: what the state before that loop? if objectPatches already holds Mat objects of the same size, .copyTo won't create a new data array but use the existent one. If for example you created the vector with `vector<Mat> objectrPatches(#size, sampleMatOfImageSize)` they will all use the same data array location. Don't know whether .clone will always allocate new memory

Comment: I have updated my post, but yes, objectPatches already holds data, that is images of the same size. I just need to re-arrange them in this step. I also tried simple assignment, but it does not work either.

Comment: the question is how the holded images were created in the very beginning. you have to make sure that they dont use the same data array, since `Mat` objects are only header objects which behave like pointer. `.clone()` might create new data arrays, but `copyTo` definitely does NOT create new data arrays if the Mat size fits the requirements, so it MIGHT be the problem that all your Mats share the same data array and `.copyTo` does not create new ones but `.clone` does

Comment: another example: `loop i=n times: objectPatches.push_back(firstImage)` will produce a vector with `n` images that all use the same data array => if you change one pixel value in any of those images you will see the change in all other ones because its the same memory they use. While `loop i=n times: objectPatches.push_back(cv::Mat()); firstImage.copyTo(objectPatches.back());` would create n empty Mat headers for which new data arrays would be created when you use them as targets for .copyTo because their sizes do not match.

Comment: THANKS. I did testing. I tried to create images as you mentioned and it is exactly as you have stated. It is really new thing for me and you have saved  my day! I would rate your answer, but I cannot see how to do that with comments.

Comment: but how were the images in `objectPatches` created in your code originally (e.g. the line of code that creates or fills the vector)? If you add that to your question text, I can write a real answer that could help someone else to understand when reading :) Otherwise dont feel blamed if you can't rate, it's ok :D

Comment: Yep, I added extra info, stating that vector was created simply using push_back() function.